# Mutidimensional integral

Tags: probability, integration, probability-theory, definite-integrals, multiple-integral

If $a > 0$, $g \in \mathbb{R}^d$ and $M$ is a covaraince matrix, where $d$ is an integer greater than 1, is it possible to compute explicitly the following integral:

\begin{equation}
 \int_{\mathbb{R}^d} {g^{T} g \exp\left(-a g^{T} M^{-1} g\right) dg}
\end{equation}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Substitute $g \mapsto a^{-1/2}M^{1/2}g$, where $M^{1/2}$ is the positive-definite square root of $M$ which commutes with $M$. Then

\begin{align*}
\int_{\mathbb{R}^d} (g^{\mathsf{T}}g) e^{-a g^{\mathsf{T}}M^{-1}g} \, \mathrm{d}g
&= \frac{\sqrt{\det M}}{a^{(d/2)+1}} \int_{\mathbb{R}^d} (g^{\mathsf{T}}Mg) e^{- g^{\mathsf{T}}g} \, \mathrm{d}g \\
&= \frac{\sqrt{\det M}}{a^{(d/2)+1}} \sum_{i,j} M_{i,j}\int_{\mathbb{R}^d} g_i g_j e^{- g^{\mathsf{T}}g} \, \mathrm{d}g.
\end{align*}

Notice that if $i \neq j$, then the integral vanishes by parity. So only the diagonal terms survive. Now using the computation

\begin{align*}
\int_{\mathbb{R}^d} g_i^2 e^{- g^{\mathsf{T}}g} \, \mathrm{d}g
= \left( \int_{\mathbb{R}} x^2 e^{-x^2} \, \mathrm{d}x \right) \left( \int_{\mathbb{R}} e^{-x^2} \, \mathrm{d}x \right)^{d-1}
= \frac{\pi^{d/2}}{2},
\end{align*}

we finally obtain

\begin{align*}
\int_{\mathbb{R}^d} (g^{\mathsf{T}}g) e^{-a g^{\mathsf{T}}M^{-1}g} \, \mathrm{d}g
= \frac{\pi^{d/2}}{2a^{(d/2)+1}} \sqrt{\det M} \operatorname{tr}(M).
\end{align*}

Comment: where does the last equality comes from? is it a known equality? Thanks.

Comment: @Jeremy, I expanded my answer. Hope this helps!